# Whats up with the tag status-bychaos?

Tags: support, tags, meta, tag-synonyms

When filtering for "status"-Tags on the [Tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags) page here on MSE, there is a tag [status-bychaos](/questions/tagged/status-bychaos). It's not editable and no questions are tagged with that tag:

> [image]

Moving the mouse on the Tag to get the Tag-Information results in a 404

```
GET https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/status-bychaos/subscriber-info?_=1398671265891 404 (Not Found)
```

But the tag [status-bychaos](/questions/tagged/status-bychaos) is a [synonym](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) of the [chaos](/questions/tagged/chaos) added back in 2012. The [chaos](/questions/tagged/chaos) is also not used by any question.

So are the tags [status-bychaos](/questions/tagged/status-bychaos) and [chaos](/questions/tagged/chaos) dead and should be burninated?

Edit: this also happens in the favorite/ignored tag autocomplete/selector:

> [image]

Comment: Those tags don't seem to exist (no empty wiki excerpt header), nor do they appear on the Tags page when filtered.  When did you last see them?  Your question is only ten minutes old and this seems like a *very* unlikely time of day for the empty tag reaper to run...

Comment: @Charles I just noticed them today, so maybe they get automatically cleaned up. But i think due to the tag synonym these tags will not get deleted by the system

Comment: @Charles I took the liberty to add a screenshot.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks for the edit

Comment: @Jehof cheers, also retagged as this is specific for meta and there is nothing to burninate, the bug is likely in the filtering.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, super, thanks.  They *do not* appear when just filtering on `chaos`.

Comment: Well, for what it's worth CHAOS used to be a [team inside Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character): "CHAOS is a team of eight full-time employees that just started working at Stack Exchange Global World Domination Headquarters in New York, NY" and next to their display name used to be a PSI character instead of diamond.

Comment: @ShadowWizard is it a deleted question. I get a 404 on the link

Comment: @Jehof yep, I quoted the essential part.

Comment: @Jehof OK, [full screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/LrRzK.jpg). (it was PNG originally, imgur converted to JPG probably to save some bytes on their server, sorry!)

Comment: I think it has something to do with [Working with the Chaos Monkey](http://blog.codinghorror.com/working-with-the-chaos-monkey/), and it's a play on `status-bydesign`. When a bug cannot be reproduced or explained, it's blamed on chaos.

Comment: The OP is right. The tags are "deleted" at the moment, but since that synonym link still exists, the system *thinks* the tag pair still exists as well. Fixing the issue is just a matter of destroying the synonym.

Comment: @animuson indeed, [there is a synonym](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POnBl.png). However, ordinary users can't delete it, can you please delete the synonym and put this issue to rest? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Gone.

Answer (score 5):

[status-actually-completed-for-real-this-time](/questions/tagged/status-actually-completed-for-real-this-time):

> [image]

Now the only chaos on Meta is the usual anarchy.

Comment: So...if it does come back...and it gets fixed again...would that be [tag:status-actually-completed-for-real-this-time-we-swear]?